# Two EditText fields with rounded cornors android

Tags: android

i have two EditText fields in my android application.I added rounded cornors to one Edittext field with XMl file.Like this
     
How to make the second EditText with rounded cornors?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: where is the xml code.. like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a drawable resource that specifies the way the EditText will be drawn:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

reference this drawable in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I will accept your answer.

Comment: I need to place the image in the middle of the EditText Field?How to do that?